# Jquery Drop Down menu blinks only on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am starting a Jquery drop down menu for a new project and it is working as expected on Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari but of course it is giving me some headache on Internet Explorer.

here's the thing, 
See this page
http://www.universidadedoingles.com.br/dev/index.ASP

on mouse over the menu HOME, the drop down appers, when you move over the links in IE you see some flashes of the background, which doesn't happens on Chrome and ETC.

here's the js coda I am using to do the dd menu.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {   
$("ul.mainmenu li.menuhome").mouseover(function(){
    $(".arrow-spacer").show(); //When mouse over ...
    //Following event is applied to the subnav itself (making height of subnav 150px)
    $(this).find('.submenu').show().animate({height: '150px', opacity:'1'},{queue:false, duration:300})     
});

$("ul.mainmenu li.menuhome").mouseout(function(){ //When mouse out ...
    //Following event is applied to the subnav itself (making height of subnav 0px)
    $(this).find('.submenu').hide().animate({height:'0px', opacity:'0'},{queue:false, duration:200})
});

//menu itembackground color animation           
$("li").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate();},
    function() {
        $(".arrow-spacer").hide();
    }); 
});
</script>
```

That's it, I guess it may be simple, but it's been weeks and I still can't get it to work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which version(s) of Internet Explorer have you tested? http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: I don't see why you want to hide "arrow-spacer" when a li element is hovered?

Comment: for some reason, if I don't use that hide(), after I hover the HOME link the fist time, the arrow-spacer wont disappear. so I need the arrow just to show when I mouse over the link and hide when I mouse out.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the anchor `<a>` tags have a margin on them. My first thing would be to try using padding instead.  IE doesn't treat a hover in the margin the same way as other browsers.

Comment: I did what you said, change margin for padding, but that was not thing causing the blinks, any other idea? thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

in some cases it helps to set a `z-index` on elements that should placed in top of other elements.

In your case I would try to set the `z-index` on `<ul class="submenu">`

Comment: hey Sarah, I've added the z-index property to the submenu, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

No blinks anymore! I changed one word hide() to stop (), now there is no blinking on iE. but...

After you show the menu 1 time, everytime you get your mouse below the link or close the link, the menu shows up again.

check this

www.universidadedoingles.com.br/dev

you'll be able to see its behavior

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the focus to `<li>` is lost when you mouse over an `<a>` element.
Here is something you could use to overcome this. I avoided using the `<a>` tag, instead I used a JavaScript function to send the user to the preferred location. I used JavaScript rather than jQuery hoping to make it more self-explanatory.

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#n li').hover(function() {
                $('ul', this).slideDown(200);
        $(this).children('a:first').addClass('h');
          }, function() {
        $('ul', this).slideUp(200);
        $(this).children('a:first').removeClass('h');   
      });
        });
        function gotoPage(pnumber){
            var goto;
            if(pnumber==1){
                goto="home.html";
            }else if(pnumber==2){
            goto="watsnew.html";
            }else if(pnumber==3){
                goto="aboutus.html";
            }else if(pnumber==4){
                goto="contactus.html";
            }
            window.location.href=goto;  
        }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#n {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    width:5em;
}
#n li { 
    /*display:inline;*/
    background: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
#n li .h { 
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #CF3;
    border-right: 1px solid #CF3;
    color: #576482;
    height:20px; }
#n ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    list-style: none
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    width:200px;
}   
#n ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:10px;}
#n ul li:hover {
    background:#960;}

</style>


<div>
<ul id="n">
   <li>MENU
      <ul >
        <li value="1" onclick="gotoPage(this.value)">HOME</li>
        <li value="2" onclick="gotoPage(this.value)">WATS NEW</li>
        <li value="3" onclick="gotoPage(this.value)">ABOUT US</li>
        <li value="4" onclick="gotoPage(this.value)">CONTACT US</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
<ul>
</div>
```